# List.Find is returning an error in C# code

Tags: c#, list, find

```
public static string[] categoryNames = new string[] { "Control", "Supplies", "Power" };
int listSelected = categoryNames.Find(item => item == "Power");
```

For some reason, I get this error over `Find` method:

> *There is no argument given that corresponds to the formal parameter 'match' of 'Array.Find(T[], Predicate)'*

I've looked through many examples, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with `List.Find()`.  Any feedback is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: An array is not a List -- if you want to use `List.Find` then you need to create a `List<T>` instead - you can do that with `.ToList()`

Comment: There is are static methods `Array.Find` and `Array.FindIndex`, but there is no instance method `Find` in arrays.

Comment: For arrays, you could use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays don't have a `Find` instance method. You need to use `Array.FindIndex()` if you want to find the index of the first element that matches the predicate.

```
public static string[] categoryNames = new string[] { "Control", "Supplies", "Power" };
int listSelected = Array.FindIndex(categoryNames, item => item == "Power");
```